# Create a search box to list all searched results in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to create a search box in excel that will return all rows that contain what is typed in that search box. Thing is, I have 28 columns, 180 rows. So as long as one of the columns contains that word, I would want that entire row to appear.

I came across this link, https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4137-excel-create-a-search-box.html it sort of answered part of what I wanted. It didn't really provide enough information to firstly: tell me what formula to input in the search box (cell B2) and secondly, this explanation was only for 1 column - whereas mine involved 28 columns.

Anyone has any clue?

Comment: I think `FILTER()` function with `MMULT()` can give you expected result.

Comment: Sorry, I am a bit lost on your point.

Comment: Put few sample data and expected output to your post. Also what is your excel version. `FILTER` function is only available to `Excel-365`.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IKzLXnuaiIGVZuFwPGcqAbICIXPFErovj4-5BzHqJco/edit#gid=0

The idea is to search in B2, and display results in A3. 

So let's say I want to list all rows with the word hindi, then row 12 will appear in cell A3.

Mine is excel 365

Comment: Try my answer and let me know your response.

Comment: It kinda works, it doesn't appear for certain search terms and it seems to take into account word variations. For example, on my master sheet, typing "axe" returns axe, relaxed

Comment: What if you make it into a table? Don't tables have built in filters?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your given sample data, I used below formula in `Excel-365`.

```
=FILTER(A11:F16,MMULT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A1,A11:F16)),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(A10:F10),,,0)))
```

[image]